# Structure and sending two arrays to the same receiving function

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, jsoup

Good morning,

I'm trying to send  two arrays (returned from getValuesGraph(doc) and getValuesFooter(doc) respectively) to the same function (OnPostExecute), I'm newbie at Java and Android and I don't now if the app code structure It's correct. So my apologies for the "disaster". 
LogCat says:

02-21 00:07:25.852: W/dalvikvm(3282): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at com.example.kwhora1.MainActivity$BackGroundTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:159)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at com.example.kwhora1.MainActivity$BackGroundTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-21 00:07:25.862: E/AndroidRuntime(3282):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here's the code:

```
package com.example.kwhora1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView tvmax, tvmid, tvmin, tvactualval;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvmax=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmaximo);
        tvmid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvmedio);
        tvmin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvminimo);

        new BackGroundTask().execute();



    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }


        public String[] getValuesGraph(Document doc) {


                int cont=24,var=7;
                String bar[] = new String[cont];



   /*
   * Getting elements from the graphic in an array from 0-23. 0 it's 1:00am, 23 it's 00:00am
   */

               for (cont=0; cont < 24; cont++){

String onMouseOver = doc.select("a").get(var+cont).attr("onMouseOver");
               bar[cont] = onMouseOver.split("'")[9];


               }


               return bar;



        }


        public String[] getValuesFooter(Document doc) {



            String values[] = new String[7];


            /*
                * Getting elements from the graphic footer
                */

               Elements elements = doc.select("td.cabeceraRutaTexto");
               elements.size(); // 6



                   /*  Getting text from table */
                   values[0] = elements.get(0).text(); // TITLE
                   values[1] = elements.get(1).text(); // TEXT MAX VALUE
                   values[2] = elements.get(2).text(); // TEXT MIDDLE VALUE
                   values[3] = elements.get(3).text(); // TEXTO MIN VALUE

                   /* Getting numbers from table */

                   values[4] = elements.get(4).text(); // NUMBER MAX VALUE
                   values[5] = elements.get(5).text(); // NUMBER MIDDLE VALUE
                   values[6] = elements.get(6).text(); // NUMBER MIN VALUE    


                   return values;


         }




        @Override
        public String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {




            try {

                URL url= new URL("http://www.mywebtoextractdata.com");
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url.toString()).get();

                getValuesGraph(doc);

                getValuesFooter(doc);

/*
* Getting elements from the graphic in an array from 0-23. 0 it's 1:00am, 23 it's 00:00am
*/




            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }





        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] values) {

            /*tvactualval.setText();*/

            tvmax.setText(values[4]);
            tvmid.setText(values[5]);
            tvmin.setText(values[6]);

            /*System.out.println(val[4]);*/
            super.onPostExecute(values);
        }




    }


}
```

Thank you in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {` you are supposed to return a String array.  So create one

```
 String arr [] = new String [2];
```

and then add the result of `getValuesGraph()` to it.

```
arr[0] = getValuesGraph(doc);
arr[1] = getValuesFooter(doc);
```

then `return` then arr

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate your help. Is this way the best way to do it? now the compiler says "cannot convert from String[] to String" because getValuesGraph(doc) return an array and I think It's trying to save an entire array in arr[0].

Comment: Yes, it is a bit messy isn't it.  I would creating a new class which holds the separate String arrays, and have that passed back from `doInBackground`

Comment: Thank you very much, finally I created a "Pair" class with the array declaration and worked with It in doInBackground. It works fine!!